# Threads sometimes do not closed after finished their code (ThreadPoolExecutor)

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
        num_of_pages = 20
        num_of_workers = num_of_pages
        pages = [i for i in range(0, num_of_pages)]
        datarALL = []
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor:
            futh = [(executor.submit(self.getdata3, page, hed, data, apifolder,additional)) for page in pages]
            for data in as_completed(futh):
                datarALL.extend(data.result())
        print ("Finished generateing data.")
        return datarALL
```

thread function is:

```
def getdata3(self, page, hed, data, apifolder, additional):
    tries = 10
    for n in range(tries):
        try:
            value_limit = self.config.page_limit  # limit of records allowed per page
            value_offset = page * value_limit
            datarALL = []
            url = 'http://www.url.com/{2}?WithTotal=true&cultureid=2&offset={0}&limit={1}{3}'.format(
                value_offset, value_limit, apifolder, additional)
            print ("{3} Generate page: #{0} run #{1} with URL: {2}".format(page, n, url,str(datetime.now())))
            responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
            if responsedata.status_code == 200:  # 200 for successful call
                responsedata = responsedata.text
                jsondata = json.loads(responsedata)
                if "results" in jsondata:
                    if jsondata["results"]:
                        datarALL.extend(jsondata["results"])
                        break   
            else:
                print ("page {0} run #{1} faild. Returned status code {2}. Message is: {3}. Retry".format(page, n,responsedata.status_code, responsedata.text))
                continue                       
        except ChunkedEncodingError as e:
            print ("page #{0} run #{1} failed. Retry.".format(page, n))
            if n == tries - 1:
                print ("page {0} could not be imported. Max retried reached.".format(page))
                print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
                raise e
    print ("{2} page {0} finished. Length is {1}".format(page,len(datarALL),str(datetime.now())))
    return datarALL
```

This create threads  and when all threads are finished it return the list called datarALL

On console I see:
[image]

This means that the last print was done and the function returned.
However on htop I see:
[image]

I shouldn't see this after the print of `Finished generating data.` I should see only the main process. For some reason not all threads are closing. I don't understand why.
I should note that this doesn't always happens.. sometimes it works ok.

I can't find out what is the problem.

Another interesting thing is that when this happens The process is killed:
[image]

But even after Ubuntu kills the process I the threads on htop as follows (only the main process was removed):

[image]

Only running

```
ps -ef | grep name | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

free the bad records...

What's going on here?

Comment: Don't see your thread code, but do you run them as daemons (daemon=True?)

Comment: @DavidBrabant The threads execute self.getdata3 functions with the given parameters.. I'll post the function.

Comment: @DavidBrabant see edit